# How to fix duplicated/echoed missed-call notifications?

Tags: notifications, google-pixel

TL/DR: How can I prevent missed call notifications from being duplicated when I dismiss them?

**Background:**

I get several phone calls per day from numbers I don't recognize.  My phone (Google Pixel XL) usually labels them as suspected spam and I press the volume button to stop the ring tone but I don't reject or answer the calls.

Shortly after the incoming call ends, I get a notification of a missed call.  When I swipe the notification to the right to dismiss it, the notification pops back up as if it was a new notification, complete with the notification sound.  As far as I can tell, this duplicate or echo of the notification is identical to the original with one exception: when I dismiss it, it does not echo or duplicate again.

Almost all missed call notifications echo like this but I have been unable to figure out why nor have I noticed any clear difference between the majority of notifications that get duplicated and the few that do not.

**Question:**

How can I prevent these missed call notifications from being duplicated?

**Details:**

Phone is the original Google Pixel XL running Android version 10 (Kernel version 3.18.137, Build number QP1A.191005.007.A3) on the Google Fi service.

Comment: Are you sure the second notification comes from your device and is identical to the first? Some mobile network provider send SMS for every missed call.

Comment: @Robert Neither notification (original or copy) is a standard SMS; they don't show up in text messages.  Also, it makes no sense to me that an SMS notification would appear only after the original is dismissed.